# precacheAndRoute TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox, web-push

I referred this article https://dev.to/ronyfr3/web-push-notification-using-react-and-node-js-oc9 to integrate WebPush notifications to ReactJs application and after configuring all the things I am getting an error when adding the following lines to custom-sw.js

```
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`self.__WB_MANIFEST` is a symbol that's [meant to be replaced](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers#optional_inject_a_precache_manifest) by one of the `InjectManifest` build tools.

If you want something that works for testing purposes without having to run a build tool, you can use

```js
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);
```

to pass in an empty precache manifest array when `self.__WB_MANIFEST` is undefined.